# ActiveRecord 4 how to user :order and :include

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I've just upgraded to Ruby 2.0 which by default will load ActiveRecord 4 for a Padrino app. This is fine, I'd like to take advantage of the Ruby 2.0 and AR 4 improvements. However, I'm having trouble rewriting some of the relations that worked before.

For example, this is no longer valid:

```
  has_many :dvd_credits, :order => 'position', :include => [:dvd_actor, :dvd_role]
```

It gives a deprecated warning, but the example it shows is useless: `has_many :spam_comments, -> { where spam: true }, class_name: 'Comment'`

Looking around I was able to find that this works by omitting the `:include` parameter:

```
has_many :dvd_credits, -> { order :position }
```

If I add it like so:

```
has_many :dvd_credits, -> { order :position, include: [:dvd_actor, :dvd_role] }
```

I get this error when I call that relation:

```
ArgumentError: Direction should be :asc or :desc
```

I'm still coming to grips with the changes to AR 4 but would really appreciate some help on this.

Thanks.

PS
I did find this in the AR 4 page:

> There's no need to use includes for immediate associations - that is,
>   if you have Order belongs_to :customer, then the customer is
>   eager-loaded automatically when it's needed.

Which I take it to mean that I can safely ignore the `include:` parameter?

But this relationship is a bit complex, it goes like this:

```
class Dvd < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :dvd_credits, -> { order :position }
  has_many :dvd_actors, :through => :dvd_credits
  has_many :dvd_roles, :through => :dvd_credits

class DvdCredit < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :dvd_actor, :inverse_of => :dvd_credits
  belongs_to :dvd_role, :inverse_of => :dvd_credits
  belongs_to :dvd, :inverse_of => :dvd_credits

class DvdActor < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :dvd_credits, :inverse_of => :dvd_actors
  has_many :dvds, :through => :dvd_credits
```

But seems to fulfill the `belongs_to` condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yea, you can just ignore the `:include` part.